# matplotlib tripcolor: mesh grid is showing up when i'm changing the alpha parameter

Tags: matplotlib, opacity, alpha, mesh

I'm trying to change the opacity of a tripcolor garph. Setting the alpha parameter is changing the opacity but is also showing up the mesh grid. I think that this is happening because the alpha parameter is not changing the opacity of the edges too. I tried to set edgecolor='none' but this is not solving my problem. Is there a way of changing the opacity without displaying the mesh grid?

```
"""
Pseudocolor plots of unstructured triangular grids.
"""
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.tri as tri
import numpy as np
import math

# Creating a Triangulation without specifying the triangles results in the
# Delaunay triangulation of the points.

# First create the x and y coordinates of the points.
n_angles = 36
n_radii = 8
min_radius = 0.25
radii = np.linspace(min_radius, 0.95, n_radii)

angles = np.linspace(0, 2*math.pi, n_angles, endpoint=False)
angles = np.repeat(angles[...,np.newaxis], n_radii, axis=1)
angles[:,1::2] += math.pi/n_angles

x = (radii*np.cos(angles)).flatten()
y = (radii*np.sin(angles)).flatten()
z = (np.cos(radii)*np.cos(angles*3.0)).flatten()

# Create the Triangulation; no triangles so Delaunay triangulation created.
triang = tri.Triangulation(x, y)

# Mask off unwanted triangles.
xmid = x[triang.triangles].mean(axis=1)
ymid = y[triang.triangles].mean(axis=1)
mask = np.where(xmid*xmid + ymid*ymid < min_radius*min_radius, 1, 0)
triang.set_mask(mask)

# Illustrate Gouraud shading.
plt.figure()
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.tripcolor(triang, z, shading='gouraud', cmap=plt.cm.rainbow, alpha=0.5, edgecolor='none')
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('tripcolor of Delaunay triangulation, gouraud shading')

plt.show()
```

Thank you very much for your time,

Dorin

Comment: It seems the be something with the `gauraud` shading. If you capture the paths from `.tripcolor` and add them again as a path collection it looks fine (but without the proper shading). That shows that the triangles are good, no overlap or anything, which is what i originally suspected.

Comment: @RutgerKassies Thank you very much for your quick replay. I'am a newbie in matplotlib and i do not understand entirely your answer. I have done something like this: plt.figure() ax = plt.gca() ax.set_aspect('equal') trip = ax.tripcolor(triang, z, shading='gouraud', cmap=plt.cm.rainbow, alpha=0.5, edgecolor='none') path = trip.get_paths() collection = mcoll.PathCollection(path, edgecolors=z) ax.add_collection(collection) but the plot is really weird. Can you copy and paste the code lines described in your comment, please? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

you can try it with: " edgecolors='k', linewidth=0.0 " so this can set the linewidth to zero, which makes the line disapp